# Is it possible to remove a Publisher Policy file?

Tags: .net, policyfiles, publisher-policy

I have a situation where a vendor-supplied assembly reference is messed up.  Basically, it is pointing to a version of the assembly that I do not want to use.  I used FusionLog to view the assembly binding log and I see these entries:

```
LOG: Publisher policy file is found at C:\WINDOWS\assembly\GAC_MSIL\policy.11.0.iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere\11.0.0.22582__f222fc4333e0d400\iAnywhere.Data.SQLAnywhere.config
LOG: Publisher policy redirect is found: 11.0.0.11292 redirected to 11.0.1.22582
```

I cannot seem to find the publisher policy file and I am wondering if there is a way to remove it?  I tried removing the assembly from the GAC but to no avail.

The background of the problem is that I was directed to install a patch for the client software from Sybase but this patch installed a version of the assembly (11.0.0.11292) that is earlier than the previous assembly (11.0.1.22582).  Don't ask me why this happened but it did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To remove the policy assembly from the GAC:

```
gacutil -u <policy-assembly-name>
```

note that  does not include the .dll at the end and to find out the proper name of the assembly being applied I used Fusion.  You can find more about Fusion [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/suzcook/archive/2003/05/29/57120.aspx) and [here](http://www.hanselman.com/blog/CommentView.aspx?guid=3654c8f3-c5c3-4dee-a01f-c9a8da3ef2fa).